# CURL script containing AWK fails over SSH to print Docker Image Digest

Tags: bash, docker, curl, awk, ssh

The following `curl` script **fails** over `ssh`,

```
    #!/bin/bash
    reg='dockreg:5000'
    image='mubu6'
    itag='v6'
    auth='-u user:pass'
    accept=(
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
    )
    
    ssh -tt root@192.168.122.60 "
    
    echo get digest; read
    curl ${auth} -vsk \
    -X DELETE \
      "https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/$(
        curl ${auth} \
        -vk "${accept[@]}" \
        https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/${itag} 2>&1 |\
    grep docker-content-digest | awk '{print $3}' |\
    tr -d $'\r'
    )"
    "
```

**without printing** the `digest` after `manifests` on the first output line below, while throwing a `404 error` on the last.

```
DELETE /v2/mubu6/manifests/ HTTP/2
> Host: dockreg:5000
> authorization: Basic YWxleGFuZGVyOnNvZmlhbm9z
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
< HTTP/2 404
```

It **runs successfully** on the node though,

```
echo get digest; read
curl ${auth} -vsk \
-X DELETE \
  "https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/$(
    curl ${auth} \
    -vk "${accept[@]}" \
    https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/${itag} 2>&1 |\
grep docker-content-digest | awk '{print $3}' |\
tr -d $'\r'
)"
```

**printing** the `digest` after `manifests` on the first line and a `HTTP/2 202 exit code` on the last:

```
DELETE /v2/mubu6/manifests/sha256:0aa2280cc066ef4f8279122fc9f76d15e96a8bfa642a54dadbf8c9985f3de747 HTTP/2
> Host: dockreg:5000
> authorization: Basic YWxleGFuZGVyOnNvZmlhbm9z
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 250)!
< HTTP/2 202
```

The failure is probably related to `awk` as it already needs `tr -d $'\r'` in order to pass the `line feed` correctly to `curl`.
Furthermore, I already know that `awk` **does not work out of the box over** `ssh` from only running successfully the following, **after  escaping** `$2` in `awk`:

```
for x in ${NODE_IPS[@]}; do
ssh -tt root@$x "
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print \$2}' | \
xargs -p dpkg --purge
echo -e "continue to next node \c"; read
"
```

Unfortunately trying **the same solution with** my `curl` over `ssh` script **throws errors**:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \$3}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: {print \$3}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
```

I 've also **tried quite a few different quoting permutations** all over the script to no avail.
I am very new to all this and any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three sets of double quotes nested inside each other.  They are causing havoc with the bash parsing.  If you want the quotes inside transported to the far end of the SSH tunnel you need to escape them with backslashes...

ssh is probably only seeing the content inside the first set of quotes:

```
ssh -tt root@192.168.122.60 "
    
    echo get digest; read
    curl ${auth} -vsk \
    -X DELETE \
      "
```

Bash has 2 types of quotes:  single quotes and double quotes.

single quotes will cause bash to NOT interpret any escapes, variables, etc. inside the string.

double quotes will cause bash to do full substitution of escapes and variables.

You can place single quotes inside double quotes and variables will still be replaced:

```
DEMOVAR="just testing"
echo "This is a 'test of $DEMOVAR' to show single quotes have no effect here"

# RESULT:
This is a 'test of just testing' to show single quotes did not affect substitution
```

But it does not work the same when placing double quotes inside single quotes:

```
echo 'This is a "test of $DEMOVAR" to show that single quotes prevent substitution'

# RESULT: 
This is a "test of $DEMOVAR" to show that single quotes prevent substitution
```

To make it more complicated, you can 'escape' doublequotes inside doublequotes, but you cannot escape single quotes inside single quotes:

```
echo "This set of \"Double quotes\" will show"
```

But single quotes will concatenate:

```
echo 'Single quotes \'will not escape\' inside single quotes'
```

The above line will open a single quote and then close it right after the first backslash-quote.  The following text: *will not escape' inside single quotes*  **is not inside any quotes** and so the second backslash-quote is escaped by bash.  Finally the quote at the end of the line **OPENS a new QUOTE block** so hitting enter will have it awaiting another quote to close the block.

Confused??? It took me years to understand this nuance

To make your code even more difficult, you are wrapping it inside an SSH which transmits the stuff from the first doublequote to the second doublequote, but the rest of the lines are not really inside double quotes.  The question is WHERE are the bash substitutions done?  You are trying a $(curl xxxxx) to get the digest but I can't really tell if you want that on the local machine or on the remote machine.

I would suggest you break up your commands into multiple SSH commands to get rid of the nesting:

```
#!/bin/bash
reg='dockreg:5000'
image='mubu6'
itag='v6'
auth='-u user:pass'
# Note I put double quotes inside single quotes
accept='-H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"'

# NOT sure what this is:
echo get digest; read

# Get the DIGEST. Note that I got rid of the 'grep'
# as awk can also filter, and I moved the 'tr' before the 'awk'
# I am only doing the 'curl' on the remote machine, and  
# the entire output is transmitted back.  The filters ('tr' and 'awk' )
# are done locally and the DIGEST variable is set locally.

DIGEST=$(ssh root@192.168.122.60 \
    "curl ${auth} -vk ${accept} https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/${itag} 2>&1" |\
    tr -d '\r' |awk '/docker-content-digest/ {print $3}');

# Now call the DELETE with the preset DIGEST.
ssh root@192.168.122.60 \
    "curl ${auth} -vsk -X DELETE https://${reg}/v2/${image}/manifests/${DIGEST}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint DavidG, I did as you suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: I expanded the answer with a lot of detail.  When nesting quotes and substitutions,  the best advice is don't if you can avoid it.  Makes it a lot more understandable and maintainable.

Comment: Yes this works!!! Thanks a lot for all the detailed explaining DavidG!